# How to perform SQL LEFT JOIN's using Django?

Tags: database, django, performance, postgresql

Essentially I need a count of each Entries Comments:

```
SELECT e.*, COUNT(c.id) as comments FROM blog_entry e LEFT JOIN blog_comment c ON e.id = c.entry_id GROUP BY e.id, e.name, e.name_slug, e.date_published, e.category, e.image, e.body, e.is_published, e.views, e.subscription_sent ORDER BY e.date_published DESC LIMIT 15;
```

But I don't know how to go about this using Django.

This is what I have so far, it works perfectly, except there's no comment count. Can someone point me in the correct direction for making joins like this using Django?

```
from project.blog.models import Entry, Comment

def index(request):
    latest_entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('-date_published')[:15]
    return render_to_response('blog/index.html', {'latest_entry_list': latest_entry_list)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

django 1.1 have support for aggregate queries, you can grab the last version via the svn trunk.
The doc is already updated

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: So there's currently no other way to handle something like this for the exception of dropping into raw SQL?

Comment: I think that this is what you want:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

isn´t it?

Comment: Yes, It's just a pain that I have to updrade to a development version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you really prefer to stick with 1.0 for now, you can use this method until you switch to 1.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by#327987

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using trunk Django (and hence can't use the new aggregation stuff) you can achieve this with a subselect passed to the extra() QuerySet argument. The Django documentation for extra() uses what you're trying to achieve as an example (under the select heading) [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none).

Answer (score 1):

Without the aggregation branch you could do the following which returns a list of 2tuples:

```
  from project.blog.models import Entry, Comment

  def index(request):
    latest_entry_list = Entry.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('-date_published')[:15]
    latest_entry_list_comment_count = [(x, x.count()) for x in latest_entry_list]
    return render_to_response('blog/index.html', {
         'latest_entry_list': latest_entry_list,
)
```

Just use this in your templates:

```
{% for entry in latest_entry_list %}
    Entry: {{entry.0}}
    Comment count: {{entry.1}}
{% endif %}
```