# group by in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can i create simple group by query in trunk version of django?

I need something like

```
SELECT name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
```

actually what i want to do is simply get all entries with distinct names.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Markdown for formatting, not BBcode or whatever that is.  Please edit your post and use four spaces of indendation to mark your code block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django equivalent for count and group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by)

Answer (score 12):

If you need all the distinct names, just do this:

```
Foo.objects.values('name').distinct()
```

And you'll get a list of dictionaries, each one with a **name** key.  If you need other data, just add more attribute names as parameters to the .values() call.  Of course, if you add in attributes that may vary between rows with the same name, you'll break the .distinct().

This won't help if you want to get complete model objects back.  But getting distinct names and getting full data are inherently incompatible goals anyway; how do you know *which* row with a given name you want returned in its entirety?  If you want to calculate some sort of aggregate data for all the rows with a given name, [aggregation support](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation) was recently added to Django trunk and can take care of that for you.

Answer (score 3):

Add .distinct to your queryset:

```
Entries.objects.filter(something='xxx').distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

this will not work because every row have unique id. So every record is distinct..

To solve my problem i used

```
foo = Foo.objects.all()
foo.query.group_by = ['name']
```

but this is not official API.

Comment: Yes and I find this most annoying too. There are occasions that the ORM creates sensible SQL but only thing that is not sensible is `group_by` and sometimes it seems to also add some extra fields to group_by nevertheless causing even more havoc. See my [django-users post if interested](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/fa68b624dfd95ccb).