# How do I get the number of objects per day using django?

Tags: django

I have a django model with a DateTimeField.

```
class Point(models.Model):
    somedata = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to get a count of the number of these objects for each day. I can do this with the following SQL query, but don't know how to do it through django.

```
SELECT DATE(`time`), Count(*)
FROM `app_point`
GROUP BY DATE(`time`)
```

Being able to restrict the results to a date range would also be good.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by

Comment: I saw that question, but there they are doing a GROUP BY on a field. I need to do a GROUP BY on a function on a field, not the field itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
from django.db.models.sql.aggregates import Aggregate
from django.db.models import Count

class Day(Aggregate):
    """Custom aggregator
    """
    sql_function = 'DATE'
    sql_template = "%(function)s(%(field)s)"

    def __init__(self, lookup, **extra):
        self.lookup = lookup
        self.extra = extra

    def _default_alias(self):
        return '%s__%s' % (self.lookup, self.__class__.__name__.lower())
    default_alias = property(_default_alias)

    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        super(Day, self).__init__(col, source, is_summary, **self.extra)
        query.aggregate_select[alias] = self

    q = Point.objects.annotate(day=Day('time')).annotate(found=Count('time')).values('day', 'found')
    # custom group by
    q.query.group_by = ["day"]

    print q
    # should return something like
    [{'found': 6, 'day': datetime.date(2010, 4, 30)}, 
     {'found': 4, 'day': datetime.date(2010, 5, 1)}, 
     {'found': 3, 'day': datetime.date(2010, 5, 2)}]
```

According [to this](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/tree/browse_frm/thread/95b33de6e3ca2cd8/db98f26020910a7f?rnum=1&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fdjango-users%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F95b33de6e3ca2cd8%3Ftvc%3D1%26#doc_50d7bac40de5bc56) post the above code would probably work only with MySql database.