# Django Grouping Query

Tags: python, django

I have the following (simplified) models:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Item(models.Model):
    donation = models.ForeignKey(Donation)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

I'm trying to display the total number of items, per category, grouped by the donation year.

I've tried this:

```
Donation.objects.extra(select={'year': "django_date_trunc('year', 
    %s.entry_date)" % Donation._meta.db_table}).values('year', 
    'item__category__name').annotate(items=Sum('item__quantity'))
```

But I get a Field Error on `item__category__name`.

I've also tried:

```
Item.objects.extra(select={"year": "django_date_trunc('year', 
    entry_date)"}, tables=["donations_donation"]).values("year", 
    "category__name").annotate(items=Sum("quantity")).order_by()
```

Which generally gets me what I want, but the item quantity count is multiplied by the number of donation records.

Any ideas? Basically I want to display this:

```
2010
  - Category 1: 10 items
  - Category 2: 17 items

2009
  - Category 1: 5 items
  - Category 3: 8 items
```

Answer (score 0):

This other post looks like what you're looking for:

[Django equivalent for count and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by)

Depending on your Django version, you may or may not be able to use it though.

Comment: I'm on Django 1.1.1 - should've mentioned that. I can do the "Items by Category" query as answered further down in that thread just fine, what I can't figure out how to do is do it across three models - Items per category grouped by Donation date. It's the third component that I'm lost on.

Comment: @matt django queries are meant to be flexible, but there are times when you simply can't use a django query to get the job done.  In this case, you might consider just using the straight sql solution.  It'd probably be more readable too at this point. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#topics-db-sql

Comment: I was afraid of that. Now to figure out the raw SQL for this query ;)

Answer (score 0):

I realize you've probably already written your raw SQL, but the following came to mind when I saw the way you want to display your data:

If it's alright to do it at the template level you might be able to make strategic use of the [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag and length filter.

Regroup takes a "list of alike objects" so a queryset might work just fine, but the docs show a list of dictionaries, so I've used values here:

```
item_listing = Item.objects.values('category__name', 'donation__entry_date')
# use your favourite method to extract the year information into a key in item_listing
item_listing = ...
```

Now in the template, something like:

```
<ul>
{% for year_group in item_listing %}
    <li>{{ year_group.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% regroup year_group.list by category__name as category_listing %}
        {% for category_group in category_listing %}
        <li>
        Category: {{ category_group.grouper }}
        Count: {{ category_group.list|length }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm not sure if the regroup tag nests well like that (haven't tried it). Also, I have no idea how well regroup performs if you've got a lot of data, but then again, there's always caching...

If you decide to use this, make sure that you take note of the ordering gotcha mentioned in the regroup docs.