# django ORM: make query

Tags: python, django, orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django equivalent for count and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by)

I'm studying django. In my project I'm having trouble with making a query with django ORM:

```
SELECT MIN( id ) AS id, domain, COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM app_competition 
WHERE word_id = 1545
GROUP BY domain
```

Help me please make this query

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some [Aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation) for this!

What you need to do in your case is two things: First, use `values` to force GROUPBY on your query, then annotate your query using the built-in functions `Min` and `Count`

If my django-orm fu is correct, your query should look something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Count

Competition.objects.values('domain').filter(word_id=1545).annotate(id=Min('id'), cnt=Count('id'))
```

Key things to note: You need to place the `values` call before any annotations to force it to GROUPBY, then the rest is pretty self explanatory.

Didn't test the query so I hope I got it right :)