# Django and Aggregate: Sum of distinct values?

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to do a django aggregate function, but am unable to produce the desired result.

What I've got:

```
income_posts.values_list('category__name','amount')
[(u'Donation', Decimal("2000.00")), (u'Paycheck', Decimal("1200.00")), (u'Donation', Decimal("1000.00"))]
```

Desired result:

```
[(u'Donation', Decimal("3000.00")), (u'Paycheck', Decimal("1200.00))]
```

I need to Sum the 'amount' fields that have the same category__name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django 3.0 introduced "distinct=True" on Sum and Avg:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#sum

Answer (score 21):

From [this answer for a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by/1317837#1317837):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
income_posts.values('category__name').order_by('category__name').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: The reason why this works is because [`.annotate()` works slightly differently after a `.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values): "However, when a values() clause is used to constrain the columns that are returned in the result set, the method for evaluating annotations is slightly different. Instead of returning an annotated result for each result in the original QuerySet, the original results are grouped according to the unique combinations of the fields specified in the values() clause."

Comment: this way you do not get `DISTINCT` and distinction is achieved by another column in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to arjun27's answer. Since that package seems to have been abandoned you might want to just copy past the 3 lines you need from it:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
class DistinctSum(Sum):
    function = "SUM"
    template = "%(function)s(DISTINCT %(expressions)s)"
```

Which can be used the same as above:

```
income_posts.annotate(total=DistinctSum('amount')
```

Comment: fine, except the case where the same amount comes from different sources

Answer (score 10):

I think this issue also related to [Combining multiple aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations).

[Here is the ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) for this bug.

We can use [**`Subquery`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)) to achieve this issue:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, IntegerField, Sum, Value, Count

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    count_model_a=Count('ModelA', distinct=True), 
    sum_model_b=Coalesce(
        Subquery(
            ModelB.objects.filter(
                MyModel=OuterRef('pk')
            ).values('MyModel_id').annotate(
                my_sum=Sum('MyModel_Field')
            ).values('my_sum')[:1],
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ),
        Value(0)
    )
).values("count_model_a", "sum_model_b")
```

I also used [**`Coalesce`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce)) function to prevent returning `None`.

The above code will run one query to DB.

Comment: Brialliant answer. This is the most underrated answer for the question. I wonder why this doesn't get enough upvotes

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Postgres, you can use the `django-pg-utils` [package](https://pypi.org/project/django-pg-utils/) for sum of distinct values.

```
from pg_utils import DistinctSum
income_posts.annotate(total=DistinctSum('amount')
```

Comment: The Github for django-pg-utils is not available anymore and the latest update was in 2017. It still works but beware with this module.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using django 2.2 LTE, this behavior can be achieved just reproducing django 3.0 commit that implements distinct for Sum:

https://github.com/django/django/commit/5f24e7158e1d5a7e40fa0ae270639f6a171bb18e

this way:

```
from django.db.models Sum

class SumDistinctHACK(Sum):
    allow_distinct = True
```

and now you can use the django 3.0 syntax:

```
queryset.annotate(
    sum_result=SumDistinctHACK(
        'relatedmodel__values_to_sum',
        distinct=True,
    )
)
```

remember to replace `SumDistinctHACK` to `Sum` if you upgrade to `django >= 3.0`

Answer (score 1):

For older version of Django use `Func`

```
queryset.annotate(
   sum_result=Sum(
        Func(F('amount'), function='DISTINCT')
   )
)
```

Comment: This works as long as you have different values(amount). Once you have the same values, it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
income_posts.values("category__name").distinct().annotate(total=Sum("amount"))
```