# Django annotation has side effect on another annotation

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

I'm running into an issue where adding an annotation to a QuerySet changes the results of previous annotations.

Here is the (simplified) setup:

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Unit(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='unit_set')

    rarity = models.IntegerField()

class Gear(models.Model):
    pass

class UnitGear(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='ug_set')
    gear = models.ForeignKey(Gear, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Annotating players with the count of rarity 7 units works well:

```py
Player.objects.annotate(
    rarity7_count=Count(unit_set__rarity=7)
).values_list('name', 'rarity7_count')

[('Player1', 170),
 ('Player2', 172),
 ('Player3', 164),
 ...,
)]
```

The values returned for `rarity7_count` above are correct.

If I add the following additional annotation, this is no longer the case:

```py
Player.objects.annotate(
    rarity7_count=Count(unit_set__rarity=7),
    gear_count=Count(unit_set__ug_set)
).values_list('name', 'rarity7_count', 'gear_count')

[('Player1', 476, 456),
 ('Player2', 490, 466),
 ('Player3', 422, 433),
 ...,
)]
```

Notice how `rarity7_count` values have changed -- these values are no longer correct! Values for `gear_count` are, however, correct.

Why is that? How can get both annotation to work without interfering with each other? I have tried all sorts of things and am currently at loss on how to do this.

Comment: Yes, since you make two `JOIN`s, this will act as some sort of "multiplier".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: can I find some documentation on this (at Django level)? How can I achieve what I intend to do here with a single QuerySet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, since now there are two `JOIN`s, and since the [**`Count(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) is the number of rows, it will thus act as some sort of multiplier.

We can however solve this by specifying `distinct=True`, like:

```
Player.objects.annotate(
    rarity7_count=Count('unit_set', distinct=True, filter=Q(unit_set__rarity=7)),
    gear_count=Count('unit_set__ug_set')
).values_list('name', 'rarity7_count', 'gear_count')
```

Note that if you want the `gear_count` to also filter on the rarity, you need to specify the `filter=` part again.

Comment: Thanks a lot -- this works. I have a follow up question: I'm now trying to add a `Sum` to this annotation: `r7_sum=Sum('unit_set__rarity', filter=Q(unit_set__rarity=7))` (reality is less trivial, but I'm adapting for the models above). With `Sum` I get a result much too large (same problem as above I assume), and with `DistinctSum` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278155/229511), the result is too low. What am I missing? Should I write a new question?

Comment: @abey: it is possible that the `filter`ing is relevant here, since for a filter, you frequently add extra constraints that something is non-nullable, so I propse that you work out a MWE that can reproduce the error.

Comment: Done, here is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567841/django-count-and-sum-annotations-interfere-with-each-other)