# Django - Annotating multiple Sum() object gives wrong result

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

**models.py** looks like this

```
class Channel(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Contract(Model):
    channel = ForeignKey(Channel, related_name='contracts')
    fee = IntegerField()

class ContractPayment(Model):
    contract = ForeignKey(Contract, related_name='payments')
    value = IntegerField()
```

When I query a model:

`Channel.objects.annotate(pay=Sum('contracts__fee'))`

It returns: **75000**. And Its correct but when I query like this:

```
Channel.objects.annotate(pay=Sum('contracts__fee'))
               .annotate(paid=Sum('contracts__payments__value'))
```

And it returns: **pay: 96000, paid: 33000**. As you can see the **pay** is changed. What is going on here? I read the ticket [#10060](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060) but no luck.

Comment: Hopefull in Django 3.0 was added a flag `distinct` for `Sum`.

Comment: I tried `distinct` but the `Contract` model have so many same value of fees so I can't use `distinct` here.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567841/django-count-and-sum-annotations-interfere-with-each-other?

Comment: Yes. That's the different question

Comment: is it acceptable to do two queries?

Comment: @Horatiu Jeflea I was wondering that is it a still bug in Django 3.0. But you have another solution its up to you

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the generated SQL query? What version of django are you using?  If this is really a bug, you should open a ticket on django I guess

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `distinct=True` in `annotate()` as below...

```
Channel.objects.annotate(pay=Sum('contracts__fee', distinct=True)).annotate(paid=Sum('contracts__payments__value', distinct=True))
```

Comment: Do you try this?

Comment: I tried it and it won't work because `Contract` and `ContractPayment` models have so many same of fees

Comment: Do you got the solution or still finding?

Comment: I achieve this with different query.  But this question is still acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries to get the desired result:

```
Channel.objects.annotate(pay=Sum('contracts__fee'))
```

and

```
Channel.objects.annotate(paid=Sum('contracts__payments__value'))
```

Comment: What if I want differentiate of `pay` and `paid`. For example: `qs.annotate(diff=F('pay') - F('paid'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using  Django3, I think this should work:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Sum
contracts = Contract.objects.filter(channel__id=OuterRef("id")).values("fee")
tot = contracts.values("channel_id").annotate(total=Sum("fee")).values("total")
Channel.objects.annotate(pay=Subquery(tot), paid=Sum('contracts__payments__value')).values()
```