# Annotate function give me a wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have set the following three models in my django app:

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nome della sottocategoria', max_length=30)

class Materials(models.Model):
    subcategory= models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    quantity=models.DecimalField()
    price=models.DecimalField()

class Costs_materials(models.Model):
    subcategory= models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
    quantity=models.DecimalField()
```

In my views I have set the following code:

```
agg=Subcategory.objects.annotate(giacenza=Coalesce(Sum('materials__quantity'), 0)).annotate(
        utilizzato=Coalesce(Sum('costs_materials__quantity'), 0))
```

All works perfectly but If I try to add another annotate function, ad example:

```
agg=Subcategory.objects.annotate(giacenza=Coalesce(Sum('materials__quantity'), 0)).annotate(
        utilizzato=Coalesce(Sum('costs_materials__quantity'), 0))
```

The result of giacenza and utilizzato are not right, but the result is double than the right. A**d example if the result must be 10, is 20**.

Where is the error??

Comment: If you make use of two one-to-many relations, you make two `JOIN`s, hence these will act as a *multiplier* of each other.

Comment: How could solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Count and Sum annotations interfere with each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56567841/django-count-and-sum-annotations-interfere-with-each-other)