# How to achieve SUM aggregate() + distinct(fields) in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

I need to aggregate **Sum** of all records in db but before it I want to remove duplicates by name (distinct)

So i try use

```
 A.objects.all().distinct('name').aggregate(total=Sum('price')
```

But I got error

```
NotImplementedError: aggregate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.
```

So, How can I achieve same result in django orm?

```
Example of table:
| name | price |
  Nick | 100 |
  Eva  | 200 |
  Nick | 100 |
```

I want to select all unigue values by name and than Sum price. The result is a simple number. 300 in this example.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371550/django-and-aggregate-sum-of-distinct-values
You can use DISTINCT on aggregate functions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#sum

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron: this means you are summing up *distinct* prices, not summing up prices of distinct *names*.

Comment: @JuanMiGabarron its not that I want.

Answer (score 2):

no i dont try but if ur table -A- like this :

```
| name | price |
  Nick | 100 |
  Nick | 100 |
  Nick | 100 |
  Eva  | 200 |
  Eva  | 200 |
  Nick | 100 |
```

the queryset : `A.objects.all().values('name').annotate(total=Sum('price'))`
will give u dict like this :

```
[{'Nick':400},{'Eva':400}]
```

try use F() objects:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F

A.objects.all().values('name').annotate(total=Sum(F('price')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using sqlite as db backend which does not support distinct on fields
The Query

```
A.objects.all().distinct('name')
```

would have raised a

```
NotSupportedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
```

exception anyway

Comment: No, I use Postgres

Answer (score 0):

```
 A.objects.all().values('name').annotate(total=Sum('price'))
```

try

Comment: Do you try your answer? 
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) not implemented.