# complex query in django where subquery exists

Tags: django

I have a table with many records and am trying to create a complex query and hoping for some help here.

models.py

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    is_annonymous   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    vote            = models.IntegerField()

    created_by        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at        = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ip_address        = models.IPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)


    #content type
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

query

```
all_votes = Vote.objects.filter(
    ~Q(created_by   = None),
)
```

Am trying to return records from Vote where created_by is not null and created_by made his first vote. Meaning, I want to only return the Vote record if user made his first vote.

Am not sure how to do such a thing, usually, on SQL, I would have to do a sub query and count the user votes and if they are equal one then return the record.

Any idea how would I do that with django models?

Comment: This question is similar. It might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by

Comment: this post is about grouping results from a queryset. In my case, I would like to filter the queryset to return the first entry only, which in a regular sql can be done with subquery count. But, even if i use the sub query count here, I cannot pass the user arguement in the child query as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this grouping with a combination of the `.values` and `.aggregate` methods.

```
from django.db.models import Q, Min
votes = Vote.objects.filter(~Q(created_by=None).values('created_by').aggregate(min=Min('created_at'))
```

Once you have that, if you want to get the actual `Vote` *instances*, you'll need to do another query and use the ids returned above.

For more information on this, check out the Django help section on [aggregate and values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

Answer (score 0):

try to left join Vote to itself `on left_vote.created_by==right_vote.created_by and left_vote.id!=right_vote.id` and filter the records that have nulls on the right of the join.