# how to filter an object_list in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class CompanyReport(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    desc = models.TextField()
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

- There is a set of companies
- Each company has an entity called `report`
- There can be multiple `reports` in an `year` for the same company

What I want to do is to make a `multilevel dropdown` menu.

1. In the first level there will be names of the company.
2. When we click on a name there will be a list of years in which the company filed reports.
3. When we click on a particular year, there will be a list of all the reports for that year.

When I was working in `php` I was able to do this using 3 different queries.

1. The first query contained the name of the companies and the number of years they filed a report
2. The second query contained number of reports for a particular company in a year
3. The third query contained all the reports sorted by the company name in ascending order.

I just ran 3 nested loop, 1 for the number of companies, the other for number of years for that company and the last for the number of reports for the company in an year and then I just displayed the next report from the list.

I can do the same using `Manager.raw` but I am unable to iterate through the objects in the template because there is only this operation available `{% for obejct in object_list %}`. I need two things

1. Way to a `number based for loop`
2. An equivalent of this php `$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);` which simply gets the next tuple from the query list.

**Output expected** The kind of output I want to show is in the screenshot that I have uploaded.

[image: Dropdown List]
Any sort of help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you need the number based for loop. The normal iterator is the correct way to do a loop in Python.

If for some reason you need the index during the loop, you would use: `{{forloop.counter}}` for a one-indexed counter or `{{forloop.counter0}}` for a zero-indexed counter.

Your syntax will look something like this:

```
{% for company in company_list %}
    {{ company.company }}
    {% for company_year in company_year_list %}
        {% if company.date == company_year.date %} #note: this is pseudocode. you need a better comparison
            {{ company_year.date }}
            {% for company_report in company_report_list %}
                {% if company_report.company == company and company_report.year = company_year.date %}
                    {{ company_report.report }}
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: **Just a clarification**
These lists `company_list`, `company_year_list` and `company_report_list` will be populated using `raw` queries because these are basically group by on different attributes?

Comment: There is one thing with the solution you have provided. It is not optimum we are looping through combinations which may not even exist in the DB. If we can have count based for loops then we can get the count of reports for each company for each year. And using the list of all the reports we can just loop through them, and the company, year and number of records will be known using the earlier lists

Comment: Sachin, you shouldn't have to use raw queries. Take a look into `extra`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by

Comment: Jordan the link which you have given me only helps in the `view` part of it. I still have problem displaying it in the template because I can't iterate through the list using a the count, and even If i can do that how will I retrieve the next object.. I can only iterate in a for loop. Hope I have made myself clear

Comment: Jordan I have added the screenshot for the type of output I am expecting. Currently I am able to achieve this by doing the following
 1. I get a list of all the company
 2. A list of all the years
 3. A list of all the reports

I iterate through the company list and year list in nested loop and from the report list show those which have that year and company. But this is a little `inefficient `

Comment: Sachin, the code I gave you is intended to be used in the template. I suppose I still don't understand what the problem is. A nested loop is not going to be inefficient unless you have a ton of entries, and it's really the only decent way to do what you're doing anyway, since you're storing it in a relational database.

Comment: Yes I think  I have been doing it wrongly, the actual code should be in the view. I really need to return a list which has an attribute company and another list of years, and the year list should have the year attribute and another nested list of the reports. But I have been struggling to do that

Comment: You should ask a new question that says you wish to do it in a view. Sample input and output will be helpful.