# Django: Aggregation does not group by an integer

Tags: python, django

I want to count on an integer variable like I would with

```
select q001_r,count(q001_r) from ProjectData group by q001_r;
```

The result should be a dictionary saying I have e.g. 100 entries with a value of q001_r == 1

I have a really simple model

```
class ProjectData(models.Model):
    """No-SQL Flatfile der Variablen"""
    caseid = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    ...
    q001_r = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and this is my aggregation funciton in the view

```
countInfosq1 = ProjectData.objects.values('q001_r').annotate(q1count=Count('q001_r'))
```

My result is not what I am expecting but:

```
[{'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 1}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 3}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 1}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 3}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 2}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 2}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 2}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 1}, {'q1count': 1, 'q001_r': 3}]
```

Comment: That should work. Is that the exact aggregation call you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django equivalent for count and group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by)