# Django groupby date column not behaving as expected

Tags: python, django

This is a simple operation in mysql - I basically just want a count of each date that appears in a row in a given table (with some additional filtering).

Here's a steamlined models.py:

```
class foo(models.Model):
    sentence = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateField()
```

Here's the current attempt I've made at querying the foo model:

```
redinfo = foo.objects.all().order_by('posted').values('posted').annotate(total=Count('posted'))
```

However when I print this to screen (in this case using pandas as follow:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(redinfo.values()))
print(df2)
```

I end up with a table that looks like this:

```
ID  sentence    posted  total
0   1528    01/11/2020  1
1   1529    01/11/2020  1
2   1530    01/11/2020  1
3   1531    01/11/2020  1
4   1532    01/11/2020  1
…   …   …   …
8612    7431    21/02/2021  1
8613    7432    21/02/2021  1
8614    7433    21/02/2021  1
8615    7434    21/02/2021  1
8616    8510    21/02/2021  1
```

I've tried all sorts of changed  to the queryset, mostly comprising of doing the operations in other orders, such as:

```
redinfo = foo.objects.all().values('posted').annotate(total=Count('posted')).order_by('posted')
redinfo = foo.objects.all().annotate(total=Count('posted')).order_by('posted')
redinfo = foo.objects.all().order_by('posted').annotate(total=Count('posted'))
```

None of which has worked. Where am I going wrong with this? I've based the above attempts on these SO questions... [Django equivalent for count and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by/1341667#1341667) and [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `.values()` while converting to data frame as calling `values()` again will override your initial call of `values('posted')`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(redinfo))
print(df2)
```